# SQL update values by comparing it to other entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I got Questionnaire Data where the same Questions got asked multiple times, sadly they didnt think of giving them different question_ids, but at least i have the timestamps of when they were answered. Similar to this

| person_id | question_id | answer | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | q1l1 | 0.4 | 12:38 |
| 12 | q1l1 | 0.7 | 12:54 |

Is there a easy way to change the question id based on timestamps?

So to grab dublicates of the same question_id for the same person_id and compare the timestamps and set the question_ids to q1l1_1 and q1l1_2

| person_id | question_id | answer | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | q1l1_1 | 0.4 | 12:38 |
| 12 | q1l1_2 | 0.7 | 12:54 |

Answer (score 0):

Window function is your approach:

```
select 
    person_id, 
    question_id || '_' || row_number() over (partition by person_id, question_id order by timestamp),
    answer numeric, 
    timestamp
from questionnaire;
```

[sql online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/972b14caa7ac16c1c7e0545bae5dc9a4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function as the following:

If you want only select the new question_id:

```
select person_id,
       question_id || '_' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
       (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY timestamp) question_id,
       answer,
      timestamp
from table_name
```

If you want to update question_id to the new value:

```
update table_name set question_id = D.new_question_id
from  
(
  select person_id,question_id,
         question_id || '_' || ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY timestamp) new_question_id,
         answer, timestamp
  from table_name
) D
where table_name.person_id=D.person_id and
      table_name.question_id=D.question_id and
      table_name.timestamp=D.timestamp
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WMvYx3-w).

I think you don't need the condition `table_name.question_id=D.question_id` since all question_ids are the same for the same user.